# Как вывести принт на lineEdit?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlineedit

Делаю тренажер по устному счету. И начал осваивать PyQT5.
В программе нужно вывести произведение двух рандомных чисел и ввести результат перемножения.

Как без интерфейса сделать понятно. Не знаю как вывести `print` в поле вывода в PyQT5.

Эта часть кода в файле **main.py**:

```
import sys,random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Ui_TestGUI2_3 import Ui_TestGUI2


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    TestGUI2 = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_TestGUI2()
    ui.setupUi(TestGUI2)
    TestGUI2.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

def Qcount(self):
    a=random.randrange(-100,100)
    b=random.randrange(-100,100)
    print(a,"*",b)#Этот принт вывести на lineEdit1
    d=int(input())
    if d==a*b:
        print("Все верно")
```

Какой метод надо использовать для вывода принта?

Эта часть в **Ui_TestGUI2_3.py** (то что создано *Qt Designer*)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_TestGUI2(object):
    def setupUi(self, TestGUI2):
        TestGUI2.setObjectName("TestGUI2")
        TestGUI2.resize(387, 315)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(TestGUI2)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 130, 158, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 30, 161, 41))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 80, 161, 41))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        TestGUI2.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(TestGUI2)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 387, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        TestGUI2.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(TestGUI2)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        TestGUI2.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(TestGUI2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(TestGUI2)

    def retranslateUi(self, TestGUI2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        TestGUI2.setWindowTitle(_translate("TestGUI2", "TestGUI2"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("TestGUI2", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    TestGUI2 = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_TestGUI2()
    ui.setupUi(TestGUI2)
    TestGUI2.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Делал такое, см. в https://github.com/gil9red/dev_window/blob/master/common.py#L39, https://github.com/gil9red/dev_window/blob/727bd18e7935f095cf3be4d5e24d812452e4c3f8/mainwindow.py#L23-L27 и https://github.com/gil9red/dev_window/blob/727bd18e7935f095cf3be4d5e24d812452e4c3f8/mainwindow.py#L72-L73. Последнее соединяет сигнал с текстом из `print` в метод, что запишет куда-то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> text : QString
>
> Это свойство содержит текст редактирования строки.
>
> Установка этого свойства очищает выбор, очищает историю отмен/повторов, перемещает курсор в конец строки и сбрасывает измененное свойство на false. Текст не проверяется при вставке с помощью [**setText**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#text-prop)().

```
self.lineEdit.setText(f'{self.a} *  {self.b} = ?')
```

---

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from Ui_TestGUI2_3 import Ui_TestGUI2
class Ui_TestGUI2(object):
    def setupUi(self, TestGUI2):
        TestGUI2.setObjectName("TestGUI2")
        TestGUI2.resize(387, 315)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(TestGUI2)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 130, 158, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 30, 161, 41))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 80, 161, 41))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        
        TestGUI2.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(TestGUI2)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 387, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        TestGUI2.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(TestGUI2)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        TestGUI2.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(TestGUI2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(TestGUI2)

    def retranslateUi(self, TestGUI2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        TestGUI2.setWindowTitle(_translate("TestGUI2", "TestGUI2"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("TestGUI2", "PushButton"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_TestGUI2):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.lineEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText('Введите ответ здесь.')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 0
        self.qcount()
        
    def qcount(self):
        self.a = random.randrange(-100, 100)
        self.b = random.randrange(-100, 100)
#        print(self.a, "*", self.b)                #  Этот принт вывести на lineEdit1
        self.lineEdit.setText(f'{self.a} *  {self.b} = ?')

    def on_clicked(self):
        d = self.lineEdit_2.text() 
        if not d:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание', 'Вам надо ввести ответ.')
            return
        try:
            d = int(d)
        except:
            d = 9999
        
        if d == int(self.a) * int(self.b):    
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Все верно', f'{self.a} *  {self.b} = {d}')
            self.qcount()
            self.lineEdit_2.clear()   
        else:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Error', f'{self.a} *  {self.b} != {self.lineEdit_2.text()} \n попробуйте еще раз.')
            self.lineEdit_2.clear()  
        self.lineEdit_2.setFocus()             
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**:

> а как разделить на 2 файла, чтобы была возможность дизайн править и добавлять функционал?

**main.py**

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Ui_TestGUI2_3 import Ui_TestGUI2


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_TestGUI2):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.lineEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText('Введите ответ здесь.')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 0
        self.qcount()
        
    def qcount(self):
        self.a = random.randrange(-100, 100)
        self.b = random.randrange(-100, 100)
#        print(self.a, "*", self.b)                #  Этот принт вывести на lineEdit1
        self.lineEdit.setText(f'{self.a} *  {self.b} = ?')

    def on_clicked(self):
        d = self.lineEdit_2.text() 
        if not d:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание', 'Вам надо ввести ответ.')
            return
        try:
            d = int(d)
        except:
            d = 9999
        
        if d == int(self.a) * int(self.b):    
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Все верно', f'{self.a} *  {self.b} = {d}')
            self.qcount()
            self.lineEdit_2.clear()   
        else:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Error', f'{self.a} *  {self.b} != {self.lineEdit_2.text()} \n попробуйте еще раз.')
            self.lineEdit_2.clear()  
        self.lineEdit_2.setFocus()             
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Ui_TestGUI2_3.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_TestGUI2(object):
    def setupUi(self, TestGUI2):
        TestGUI2.setObjectName("TestGUI2")
        TestGUI2.resize(387, 315)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(TestGUI2)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 130, 158, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 30, 161, 41))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 80, 161, 41))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        
        TestGUI2.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(TestGUI2)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 387, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        TestGUI2.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(TestGUI2)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        TestGUI2.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(TestGUI2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(TestGUI2)

    def retranslateUi(self, TestGUI2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        TestGUI2.setWindowTitle(_translate("TestGUI2", "TestGUI2"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("TestGUI2", "PushButton"))
```

Comment: а как разделить на 2 файла, чтобы была возможность дизайн править и добавлять функционал?

Comment: @Era_of__ enlightenment я добавил обновление в свой ответ, проверьте. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour